# How to make entry in RemoveFile table of MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation, setup-deployment

What entry would I need to put in the `RemoveFile` table of an MSI for it to remove files from `%APPDATA%` when uninstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppDataFolder` or, if your description was loose, perhaps `LocalAppDataFolder` to reference the `%APPDATA%` folder.